# Android Sdk Versions Found N/A

Tags: react-native

Unable to Build my react-native app due to Android SDk not found even i have installed all the require Sdks and other build tools and also set Envirmental  Variables.

## npx react-native doctor

```
\`⠋ Running diagnostics...\* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

* daemon started successfully
  Common
  ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
  ✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies

Android
✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android  
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

- Versions found: N/A
- Version supported: 33.0.0
  ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

Errors:   1
Warnings: 0

Usage
› Press f to try to fix issues.
› Press e to try to fix errors.
› Press w to try to fix warnings.
› Press Enter to exit.\`
```

## When i press f to fix the issues it download the cmdline tools and give me the log

## ⚠ Android SDK configured but virtualization could not be enabled.

[Virtualization is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl0g5.png)

## npx react-native info

```
`info Fetching system and libraries information... System:   OS: Windows 10 10.0.19044   CPU: (4) ia32 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz   Memory: 5.05 GB / 7.91 GB Binaries:   Node:     version: 18.15.0     path: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.EXE   Yarn: Not Found   npm:     version: 9.5.0     path: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm.CMD   Watchman: Not Found SDKs:   Android SDK: Not Found   Windows SDK: Not Found IDEs:   Android Studio: AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996   Visual Studio: Not Found Languages:   Java: 17.0.7   Ruby: Not Found npmPackages:   "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found   react:     installed: 18.2.0     wanted: 18.2.0   react-native:     installed: 0.72.4     wanted: 0.72.4   react-native-windows: Not Found npmGlobalPackages:   "*react-native*": Not Found Android:   hermesEnabled: true   newArchEnabled: false iOS:   hermesEnabled: Not found   newArchEnabled: Not found`
```

## Environmental Variables

[VAriables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxbBI.png)
[Paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsLZg.png)

## Android SDK and other tools

i have reinstall the cmdline tools and sdk 33.0.0 but the issue is same .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your android directory you must have a `local.properties` file that points to the location of your Android SDK. In this file, all you need is a single line:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk
```

Note that this might *not* be the location of your SDK.

Comment: info JS server already running.

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor


error Failed to install the app.

Comment: You may have to clean the build folder. Navigate to the android directory and run `./gradlew clean`. Then restart the server.

Comment: when i try this command /.gradlew  clean its says there is a issue with java_home variable and i set the right path now its working

Comment: @AbdulRehman  I was just wondering where did you set the java_home variable in the bashrc file or did you set it some where in the android studio configurations.

I have already set this on my ubuntu bashrc file, but still I get the message when I do ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 0):

install the cmdline-tools if u already installed ,try to reinstall it and storage need the space , if there is no space and already installed the sdk  issue is not  solve , if u have to  solve the issue try to clean the space and reinstall it thn it will work

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a chat forum, so please avoid using SMS-style abbreviations. Instead, use full, formal English.

Answer (score -1):

There was issue in **JAVA_HOME** variable .I have not set JAVA_HOME variable in system variable that path was not correct .Now everything working fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).